# Why is differential work given as $dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition

Why is differential work given as $$dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}~?$$ Because, as I know the work done by a constant force is given as $W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$, so if the point of application of force is not moving in a straight line with the force acting on the point of application being variable too, then shouldn't the differential work be given as $d{W}=d(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r})=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}+d\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$. I know that the second term kind of feels out of place but why is it that it is not included in the expression of the differential work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like CR Drosts answer and when he says 'energies are a different way thinking about/phrasing Newtons laws', it's exactly how I like to look at it, but I want to adress the question a bit more concise.

For me, it starts with looking at $\vec{r}$ as a position and $\Delta \vec{r}$ as a displacement. This results in

> The work by a constant force $W = \vec{F}.\Delta \vec{r}$

and not $\vec{F}.\vec{r}$, which has the same unit, but not the same meaning.

The step from the work by a constant force to the work by a non-constant force (and thus the use of $dW$), is easiest made graphically:

The non-constant force below is easily divided in constant parts. In every part it is clear that

> $W_i = F.\Delta x$ and $W_{tot}=\sum W_i$

[image]

For a more thrilling non-constant force, you will have to divide the function into infinitesimal small parts, where you can assume $F$ is constant (if you take the limit $\Delta r\rightarrow 0$, this actually is mathematically correct).

If you see the analogy with the first graph, it should be clear that

> $\Delta W = F.\Delta r$ or if $\Delta r\rightarrow 0$: $dW = F.dr$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't accepted an answer yet so I will throw my hat in the ring. As a point of terminology let me define the $\Delta$ operator between two situations that we will call 0 and 1, so that for any symbol $X$ we have $\Delta X = X_1 - X_0.$ (So there is an original position $\vec r_0$ and a final position $\vec r_1$ and $\Delta \vec r = \vec r_1 - \vec r_0;$ similarly there is an original/final kinetic energy $K = \frac12 m v^2.$)

What matters is **not** some formula $W = \vec F \cdot \vec r$ or so, what matters is the formula $W = \Delta K,$ work is a change in kinetic energy. If you don't preserve the work-energy theorem then any definition of work is useless!

You are correct that for a **constant force** the formula that arises from this is $W = \vec F \cdot \Delta \vec r,$ where $\Delta \vec r = \vec r_1 - \vec r_0$ is the distance that the object has gone under this work. **If** (and it's a big if!) you choose the origin of your coordinates to start at $\vec 0 = \vec r_0,$ then you will certainly get the formula you specified. For other origins, the work-energy theorem must never be written as $\vec F\cdot\vec r$ without the $\Delta$. (Just imagine if we choose $\vec 0$ to be somewhere in the Andromeda Galaxy so that $|\vec r_1| \approx |\vec r_0| \approx \text{2.5 M light-years}$ to see why. A puny 1-newton force would have to correspond to like 10<sup>22</sup> J, which is huge—something like the amount of energy the Earth receives from the Sun every day. So it *has* to be a difference between the starting and ending points, not some origin-dependent number, if it's going to be physically meaningful.)

Now, you ask, what if the force is not constant? I'll do you one better: what if there are also multiple forces? We have Newton's law, $$m \frac{d\vec v}{dt} = \sum_i \vec F_i~~,$$and I will invite you to dot both sides with $\vec v$ to find $$m \frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot \vec v = \sum_i \vec F_i\cdot\vec v~~,$$and these terms $P_i = \vec F_i \cdot \vec v$ could be called the *power expended by* force #$i$. So much for the right-hand side. What about the left hand-side? To do this, observe that due to the same product rule that you want to apply above, $$\frac{d}{dt} v^2 = \frac{d}{dt} (\vec v \cdot \vec v) = \frac{d\vec v}{dt} \cdot \vec v + \vec v \cdot \frac{d\vec v}{dt} = 2 \frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot \vec v.$$Now normally we write equations forward to back, like "you start on the left and you end up on the right", and I did that above because I want you to follow the derivative with respect to time that way. However these things are **equal** and therefore you can also follow the logic from the right hand side back to the left-hand side. And that's precisely what I want you to do. Assuming $\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$ is the last step, yielding:$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m v^2\right) = \frac {dK}{dt} = \sum_i \vec F_i \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}.$$This is just the differential form of the work-energy theorem and now all doubts should be soothed; $P_i = \vec F_i \cdot \vec v,$ the power expended by a force, is precisely the term which tends to increase or decrease kinetic energy.

We can go one further of course; as the left-hand side indicates, a time integral is appropriate here, yielding$$\Delta K = \sum_i \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt~\vec F_i(t) \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}.$$However as long as the particle does not come back to the same point twice (or even if it does, as long as we're very careful about how we perform the integral, splitting it piecewise around these points) we can regard $\vec F$ as depending not upon $t$ but upon the position $\vec r(t)$ that the particle is located at at this time, in which case we see the familiar $u$-substitution rule that $\int dx~f(x)~\frac {du}{dx} = \int du~f(x(u)).$ It trivially holds for the dot-product and vectors too, since we **define** the line-integral as parameterizing the path as $\vec r(s)$ for $s : 0 \to 1$ and then $$\int_{\vec r(0)}^{\vec r(1)} d\vec r \cdot \vec f(\vec r) = \int_0^1 ds~\vec f(\vec r(s)) \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{ds}.$$ We basically just substitute $s = (t - t_0)/(t_1 - t_0)$ to get the equivalence. Therefore:$$\Delta K = \sum_i \int_{\vec r_0}^{\vec r_1} d\vec r \cdot \vec F_i = \Sigma_i W_i,$$ where $W_i = \int_{\vec r_0}^{\vec r_1} d\vec r \cdot \vec F_i$ is the "partial work" done by one of the forces.

That's why this is the right definition of "work" to fit the work-energy theorem, and it is fully compatible with time-varying forces. I like to advertise to kids that energies are thus a "different way of thinking about Newton's laws," which turns out to be profoundly true.

With that said the *equations of motion* will be very complicated from this energy-perspective if $\vec F_i$ does not have its usual "hey, it doesn't matter what $t$ actually is!" conservative character to it (like $1/r^2$ force laws have, for example), because you find yourself in a situation of "I can't figure out the path without the work, I can't figure out the work without the path!" circularity. That sometimes trips up the kids I tutor. It turns out that this *can* be resolved and you can do all of classical mechanics by looking at energies; this is called "Lagrangian mechanics" and is a standard tool in every physicist's toolbox. But this answer is long enough without going into the "variational calculus" that enables *that*.

Comment: I wonder what effects are captured if the dm/dt term is not set to zero. Do you get fusion/fission or something maybe?

Comment: @Emil maybe, but the usual relativistic story is that all energy warps spacetime, not just rest-mass energy. In that case you basically run into the same task either way: define your "rocket" as made up of many little masses (resp. energies), and then specify exactly what reference frame they fly off in.

Comment: @CRDrost- What do you mean when you say that "For other origins, the work-energy theorem is not true. (Just imagine if we choose $\vec 0$ to be somewhere in the Andromeda Galaxy so that $|\vec r_1| \approx |\vec r_0| \approx \text{2.5 M light-years}$ to see why." Are you saying that the origin is not still $\vec{r_0}$, and hence from the origin the two points under consideration seem to coincide, if so then the difference in their position vectors still remain the same w.r.t the new origin, displaying the dependence of position vector of $\vec{r_1}$ wrt $\vec{r_2}$. Isn't that write.

Comment: Yeah I guess "is not true" should be "is not true in the $\vec F \cdot \vec r$ form without the $\Delta$." The point is that $\vec r_1 - \vec r_0$ is origin-independent; it does not matter what point you take to be at position $\vec 0 = [0, 0, 0]$, and this is important for the theorem to mean something simple: otherwise the work done by a force can be as high as you'd like by choosing a suitably far-away origin, and it's harder to relate that back to a difference in kinetic energies.

Comment: Note that the work done by a force *can* be made as high as you'd like by changing reference frames hence $\vec v$, but that of course changes the kinetic energy nonlinearly (since it has a $v^2$ in it) so it's not too hard to see why the work-energy theorem is preserved by such changes: even though the kinetic energy and work are both reference-frame-independent they both "vary together" in the right way to keep the theorem true.

Comment: Sorry, prev comment should say “reference frame **dependent**,” not independent.

Answer (score 2):

You said

> the work done by a **constant force** is given as $W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$

which is true. Then, just doing math, we'd have $dW=d\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}+\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$. But we already said $\vec{F}$ was constant! Thus, $d\vec{F}=0$, so our formula reduces to $dW=\vec{F}\cdot{dr}$.

Then you might step back and ask, what if $\vec{F}$ is not constant? Then you can't use the formula you quoted! The formula for a non-constant $\vec{F}$ is

$$
W=\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}
$$
where now $\vec{F}$ is a function of $\vec{r}$. From this formula, it's clear that in this case, $dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ as well.

In response to your comment:

If you have a non-constant force, you want to divide your path up into many pieces $d\vec{r}$ over which the force is approximately constant. Then on each of these pieces $d\vec{r}$ you can apply the constant force equation to find the work done over the distance $d\vec{r}$, $dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$.

Comment: So, to ask why is differential work done by a non-constant force is given by $dW=\vec F\cdot d\vec r$, instead of starting from defining work done by a constant force and then differentiating it, I should have started from how do we deduce that the differential work done by a non-constant force is given by $dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$, am I right? And, if I am right then I shall ask the same question " how do we deduce that the differential work done by a non-constant force is given by $dW=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$"?

Comment: @user350331 see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Work is **defined** by:
$$
W := \int_\gamma\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r
$$

That is, a line integral over path $\gamma$. If your path is a line, that is:
$\gamma = \{\mathbf p_0 + \mathbf s t : t\in[0, h]\}$, and the force $\mathbf F$ is constant, then, you can evaluate the integral:

$$
W = \int_\gamma\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r = 
\int_0^h\mathbf F(\mathbf r(t))\cdot\mathbf r'(t)dt = 
\int_0^h\mathbf F(\mathbf p_0 + \mathbf s t)\cdot\mathbf sdt = 
\mathbf F\cdot\int_0^h\mathbf sdt = \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf sh
$$

That is, $W = \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf r$, if we let $\mathbf r =\mathbf sh$ be the displacement vector. Notation: $h$ is distance and $\mathbf s$ is direction unit vector and $\mathbf p_0$ is the initial vector (position at $t=0$). Now, if you take the differential of the work by constant force over line:
$$
dW = \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r + d\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf r
$$

Since it has constant force, then $d\mathbf F = \mathbf 0$, then we are left with the usual differential of work: $dW = \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r$. As it should be. After all, the definition is valid for all forces (constant or not).

Comment: what if the force is variable too, as I had stated in my post.

Comment: The work element dW represents force and movement.   The 'dr' is the movement-indicating element, but dot product with 'r' is a positional indication.   Work doesn't depend on the coordinate system you use for the position.   There's NO meaning in the dot product with r, in this case.

Comment: @Whit3rd-So, what you mean is that if we had defined work in a way that also included the significance of the coordinate where the point of application of force is then, there would have been significance of the term $d\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf r$

Comment: @Whit3rd- On second thoughts, how do you conclude that $\mathbf r$ is a positional indication, because if that is so, then the answer posted by Physicist137 defines work as $W=\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf r$ which does indicate that work depends on positional indication. But, if you take $\mathbf r$ as change in position or displacement vector then all comes out to be fine for the defining of $W$ but the second term in $dW=\mathbf F . d\mathbf r + d\mathbf F + \mathbf r$ can be defined as change in force as the point of application of force moves from initial point to final point, now there's a prob

Comment: What I actually mean, is that work is defined as integral of |F|  times cosine(theta) |dR|,  and the theta is to be the angle between F and the particle movement element, dR.   The "dF <dot> R"  doesn't have the correct cosine(theta) part for the definition of work.  It isn't a term we ought to add.

Comment: In the logic of the OP @user350331: why are you using the differential $$dW=\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r$$ under the integral for the total work $W$ and not $$dW = \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r + d\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf r ~?$$ ?

Comment: @freecharly Because its the definition. And OP hasn't asked why work is defined the way it is.

Comment: @user350331 Be aware that $W = \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf r$ has no position dependence, since $\mathbf r$ is the displacement, not position. That is, $\mathbf r = \mathbf s h$. Thus, if you move the same amount $h$, under same constant force $\mathbf F$, you will get the same work, no matter what your coordinates is.

Comment: @Physicist137 - You are, of course, right! I only wanted to point out that the  differential $dW=\vec F d\vec r$ questioned by the OP is also part of your  integral definition of the work.

Comment: @Physicist137 - the "W=F⋅r" formulation came from doing the indefinite integral, and should properly HAVE A CONSTANT OF INTEGRATION added in.   The constant -F⋅r_initial would be appropriate.   Expressing these ideas in formula form becomes confusing.  By itself, 'r' does have the coordinate origin as an unintended and inappropriate element.

Comment: @Whit3rd It came from a line integral (with a well defined specified line), which got transformed into a **definite integral**. There is no integration constant thus. In addition, $\mathbf r$ was defined to be the displacement, since the definition of the line I got from point $\mathbf p_0$ and arrived at point $\mathbf p_0 + \mathbf r$, where $\mathbf r = \mathbf s h$, where $\mathbf s$ is unit direction vector. All of it is clearly explained in the answer.

Comment: @Physicist137 It is NOT clearly explained, because 'r' is not a line segment, indicating a movement, it is a position.   'dr' is a line segment (though infinitesimal) and is in the direction of movement.

Comment: @Whit3rd I admit, $\mathbf r$ is usually the position in general texts. But the mathematical construction I made is clear: in this case $\mathbf r$ is not position. Its displacement. This fact reads clearly from the sentence that defined $\mathbf r$ in the answer: "That is, $W = \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf r$, if we let $\mathbf r =\mathbf sh$ be the displacement vector.". I don't get it what you said it is not well explained...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you were allowed to write $d{W}=d(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r})=\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}+d\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$ then the second term is zero because the force is not moving.
All that is happening is that you have a force acting at fixed position $\vec r$ which changes ie the force is not moving.

You also have to be careful as to the meaning of $dW$.
It does not mean $W_{\text{final position}} - W_{\text{initial position}}$ but rather it means the (infinitesimally small) amount of work done when the force $\vec F$ moves with the displacement being $d \vec r$.
Thus your $dW$ is equal to just $\vec F \cdot d\vec r$.

Answer (score -1):

$W=\vec{F}.\vec{r}$ is the work done by a constant force $\vec F$ acting over a finite distance $\vec r$. Therefore the differential $dW=d(\vec{F}.\vec{r})=\vec{F}.d\vec{r}+d\vec{F}.\vec{r}$ is the infinitesimal change of this finite work $W$ for infinitesimal changes of the force $\vec F$ and the distance $\vec r$. Thus this differential is not the infinitesimal work done by the force $\vec F$ over the infinitesimal distance distance $d\vec r$ which is correctly hgiven by $$dW=\vec F d\vec r$$

Comment: What if the applied force is variable for $d{x}$ change in the displacement too, for example consider an exponentially growing force w.r.t to displacement such that even for an infinitesimally small change in $x$ the force grows up considerably and cannot be approximated to be constant for that $dx$ interval, then we cant use the expression $dW=\vec F d\vec r$ for the differential work, or can we?

Comment: @user350331 - You can always add differentials of higher order. If you consider also the change of the force $d\vec F$ over the infinitesimal distance $d\vec r$, the expression for the work would be $$dW=\vec F d\vec r + \vec dF \vec dr$$ The second term is, however, small of the second order and can be neglected if $d\vec r$ and $d\vec F$ is small enough.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "You can always add differentials of higher order". And how did you get the expression $dW=\vec F d\vec r + \vec dF \vec dr$

Comment: @user350331 I think the important takeaway is that the formula $\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$ ONLY applies if $\vec{F}$ is a constant, therefore $d\vec{F}=0$. If $\vec{F}$ is not constant, then the formula $\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$ doesn't apply, and you have to use the integral formula.

Comment: @user350331 -$$ dW=(\vec F+d\vec F)d\vec r=\vec F d\vec r + \vec dF \vec dr$$

Comment: The work is the integral of all the dW parts.   So, the item inside the integral,  F<dot> dR, is identically dW.    There's no justification for another term.

Comment: @Whit3rd - You are right, there is no justification for another negligible term in the differential inside the intergral.